# Webpage expires on clicking on back button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on a Website on ASP.NET using C#. Most of its pages are displaying data in a Grid View and in Crystal Reports. Every time I click back button from Crystal Report page or any other page for going to the previous page which was displaying data in a GridView the webpage displays the message "Webpage has expired" in all the browsers. Is there any way to solve this issue? any help will be really useful.

Thanks,

Ekta

Answer (score 0):

Could you double check your code's where you are clearing your cache & setting the expiraton policy.
1. WebConfig.
2. Master Page.
3. Associated pages.